# Intelligencia UrlRewriter PostBack Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

i am using Intelligencia UrlRewriter for converting my page

> www.mywebsite.com/subject.aspx?subject=sub1

to

> www.mywebsite.com/subjects/sub1.aspx

On this page, I have next and previos buttons to browse the different subcategories on that subject and have used DataList with paging to support that.

When the page is first shown(IsPostBack=False) it works fine, but when next button is fired, the URL converts into this:

> www.mywebsite.com/subjects/subject.aspx?subject=sub1

Is there any idea why it is happening ?

My web.Config file is as follows :

Mt web hosting company uses IIS 7.

EDIT: I have windows 7 and I tried by using local IIS and it ran fine there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code this in your master page for this problem

Here `form1` is the `form` tag and place it in master page's load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
}
```

Comment: I am using the Form.browser and also the custom adapter, do I still have to use what u suggested?

Comment: THANKS A LOT ! I TRIED AND IT WORKED FINE.(caps because i needed it so badly !)